# Can't get new controller or view to work in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view

I'm making an project for a online car dealership, for a final exam in ASP.NET.

I created a new project, but when i click to edit an item in the site, it just opens the path to the View for editing, with the correct ID of item: https://localhost:44335/Cars/EditCar/1  but the displayed page is just black with nothing in it, without getting any errors.

This is the code in the controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult EditCar(Car carToEdit)
        {
            this.carService.EditCar(carToEdit);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

This is in the services:

```
        public void EditCar(Car carToEdit)
        {
            var editedCar = this.GetById(carToEdit.Id);

            editedCar.Picture = carToEdit.Picture;
            editedCar.Brand = carToEdit.Brand;
            editedCar.Model = carToEdit.Model;
            editedCar.Engine = carToEdit.Engine;
            editedCar.HorsePower = carToEdit.HorsePower;
            editedCar.ManufactureDate = carToEdit.ManufactureDate;
            editedCar.TotalMileage = carToEdit.TotalMileage;
            editedCar.Features = carToEdit.Features;
            editedCar.SalePrice = carToEdit.SalePrice;
        }
```

And this is the code applying to the item i want to edit:

```
<a class="text-white float-right" asp-controller="Cars" asp-action="EditCar" asp-route-id="@car.Id"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a>
```

I tried to modify the controller return paths, double checked everything from an old project with the same functions to make sure i haven't messed anything, but i can't get it to work. In the project, i have a seperate controller for the different pages in the site, so i made a new project with the very basic of what my exam project contains, but instead kept everything in the HomeController only, and it worked. So i think this might be something wrong with my controller.

Comment: Two things i noticed from your question. 1. You did not specify whether this is an asp.net core mvc application or dotnet framework 5 (asp.net mvc) application. 2. Your EditCar method or service did not contain a Save statement after assigning values to the fields. Ensure that your question is right and appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  an ancor tag from your code. It always creates a GET request. You have to use a sumbit method in you view since you need to POST the whole car model, not just a car Id

```
@model Car
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditCar", "Cars", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)

             ..... your view html

        <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" />
}
```